# TikZ spy and PGFPlots fill between

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, spy

I used PGFPlots library `fillbetween` to create a plot, and now I want to magnify part of it using TikZ `spy` library.
However, when I do it the filled area between plots disappears, both from the magnification and from the original plot.
How can I use both?

Minimal working example:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ticks = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    axis line style = {draw=none},
]
\addplot [
    name path=lower,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    name path=upper,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    fill = gray,
    opacity=.1
] fill between[of=upper and lower];
\addplot[
    no marks,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    axis line style = {draw=none},
]
\addplot [
    name path=lower,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    name path=upper,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    fill = gray,
    opacity=.1
] fill between[of=upper and lower];
\addplot[
    no marks,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.5, 1);
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 5, 0);
\end{axis}
\spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: Results with and without spy]

Comment: For the record: This is an already documented bug in the PGFPlots Tracker ([bug #103](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/103/)). Currently it is unclear if this is a bug in PGFPlots `fillbetween` or TikZ's `spy` library.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with `pgf` itself, and also with the `spy` library. Actually, there are two independent problems:

### Original plot

You wrote that the filled area disappears from the plot. When you use the fillings between plots, `pgfplots` automatically enables layered graphics. However, this is a bit problematic.

Already in the `pgfplots` manual, you can read ("Using Predefined Layers" section) that there are different places at which layered graphics can be activated: Before the `axis`, as a parameter to the axis and outside of the picture. In our case, since it is implicitly done, we are in the same category as "as a parameter to the axis". This means that `pgfplots` tries to communicate the layers outside to the surrounding `tikzpicture`. But you can read that there is a limitation to this mechanism: no environment or local TeX groups are allowed. However, the `spy` library does precisely that: It wraps the content of whatever is within such a `spy scope` in a box and with this adds several TeX groups. Therefore, `pgfplots` internally draws the axis, filling, content... all on different layers, but the surrounding `pgfpicture` does not know about this and only draws the `main` layer. As a consequence, everything that is not on this layer is lost.

A very simple fix is to activate the layers before entering the `spy` scope. This means when you attach the scope to a `tikzpicture`, write `\pgfplotsset{set layers}` before the picture (probably in a group if you don't want it for all graphics). If you attach it to an internal scope, use `/pgfplots/set layers` as a parameter to the `tikzpicture`.

Note that the `axis` environment might change the layers, for example if you use the `axis on top` key. Such a change will not survive the grouping and hence, you must already specify the correct layer when you activate the layers.

In order to avoid this, we can patch the `spy scope` command such that it is ensures the inner layer list is transported to the outside. Using `etoolbox`,

```
\tikzset{spy scope/.append code={
   \patchcmd\tikz@atend@scope{\egroup\egroup}{%
      \pgf@remember@layerlist@globally%
      \egroup\egroup%
      \pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global%
   }{}{}
}}
```

will do. `\pgf@remember@layerlist@globally` stores the current layerlist in a global macro; it is restored with `\pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global`. This is the way `pgf` transports the layer list through the several groups of a picture that in fact always exist.

As a side not, I am not so happy with this approach, for the following reason. This remark is not really relevant for your problem, but it first lead me to a wrong conclusion of what is responsible.
The implementation above works fine if every "remember" is very closely followed by a "restore". The code I gave might only break if someone does something bad with `\aftergroup` and therefore manages to inject a code between the two layer list accesses. But this is very unlikely. However, see the implementation of `\endtikzpicture`:

```latex
\def\endtikzpicture{%
   ...
   \pgf@remember@layerlist@globally
   \endscope%
   ...
   \pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global
\endpgfpicture\endgroup}
```

Here, I skipped the irrelevant and harmless parts. The problem now is that `\endscope` is a `tikz` command that calls `\tikz@atend@scope` at the very beginning. However, this is a *user-defined* command that is actually filled by specifying the `execute at end scope` key. Therefore, arbitrary code can easily be injected between those two accesses of the layerlist. Now, this is bad, because this arbitrary code could, in principle, create another (nested) picture. Hence, this nested picture is processed completely, which involves multiple invocations of the layer list. By no means must the subpicture have the same layers as the parent one - but they write to the same global macro and finally, we restore and an invalid layer list will appear in the parent picture. As a consequence, `\endpgfpicture`, which is responsible for actually drawing the layers, will in fact not draw them, or at least in a way we don't want it to do.

Now, this might seem unlikely, because who will ever draw a nested picture in an `execute at end scope` command? Well, the `spy` library does. In this way, the zoomed region is created. Luckily, the internal picture does not make use of layers, so that the layer list is not disturbed. But in use cases, this might happen. I would therefore favor an approach that uses the local grouping instead of global macros. The following patch should work (needs `letltxmacro`).

```
\newcount\aftergroupDef@usages

\newrobustcmd*\aftergroupDef[2][1]{%
   % Store the current meaning in a global variable with a unique name
   \global\advance\aftergroupDef@usages\@ne%
   \expandafter\GlobalLetLtxMacro\csname aftergroupDef@defs@\the\aftergroupDef@usages\endcsname#2%
   % To restore, define the parameters of our macro
   \csxdef{aftergroupDef@restores@\the\aftergroupDef@usages}{%
      \noexpand\aftergroupDef@restore%
         {#1}%
         \expandafter\noexpand\csname aftergroupDef@restores@\the\aftergroupDef@usages\endcsname%
         \noexpand#2%
         \expandafter\noexpand\csname aftergroupDef@defs@\the\aftergroupDef@usages\endcsname%
   }%
   % And finally inject the restore command into the stream
   \expandafter\aftergroup\csname aftergroupDef@restores@\the\aftergroupDef@usages\endcsname%
}
\def\aftergroupDef@restore#1#2#3#4{%
   % Our first parameter contains the remaining counts
   \count255 #1\relax%
   \advance\count255 -1\relax%
   \ifnum\count255>0%
      \xdef#2{%
         \noexpand\aftergroupDef@restore%
            {\the\count255}%
            \noexpand#2%
            \noexpand#3%
            \noexpand#4%
      }%
      \aftergroup#2%
   \else%
      % Cleanup
      \aftergroup\global\aftergroup\undef\aftergroup#2%
      \aftergroup\global\aftergroup\undef\aftergroup#4%
   \fi%
   % The third parameter is the local macro name, which needs to be set to the fourth
   \LetLtxMacro#3#4%
}

% Patch errors in pgf
\def\pgf@remember@layerlist@globally{%
   \aftergroupDef[2]\pgf@layerlist%
}
\let\pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global\relax
% Correspondingly address pgfplots
\patchcmd\endpgfplots@environment@opt
   {\aftergroup\pgf@remember@layerlist@globally}{}
   {}
   {\ClassWarning{bd.cls}{failed to patch endpgfplots@environment@opt}}
\tikzset{spy scope/.append code={
   \patchcmd\tikz@atend@scope{\egroup\egroup}{%
      \aftergroupDef[4]\pgf@layerlist%
      \egroup\egroup%
   }{}{}
}}
```

Here, I first define `\aftergroupDef` (adapting some code from the discontinued `etextools`), which allows to keep the definition of a macro alive after the current, and optionally more (optional parameter), groups. Then, I patch the two layer list commands. I searched the whole CTAN and only found `pgf` and `pgfplots` make use of these. In almost all cases, the appropriate replacement is to remember the layer list for *two* nested levels. One additional patch is required for the `\end{pgfplots}`. However, the spy scope code of above needs to be adjusted such that the layerlist is remembered for four levels.

### Zoomed plot

You will observe that still there is no filled area in the zoomed plot. This is due to the way in which `spy` works. As I described above, it makes use of the `execute at begin/end scope`. It basically captures everything that is within the scope into a box. But using these "hook" is a feature that `tikz` provides, which is a layer *on top of* pgf. However, drawing the layers is something that happens in `pgf`. If you look at the definition of `\endpgfpicture`, there is a call to `\pgf@insertlayers`. Before this call, the other layers (different from `main`, which is treated in a special way) are simply not present! But the box that the `spy` package creates is ended far before this drawing of the layers. So in this way, you can never get the other layers included.

The way around this is to change the behavior of the `spy` library. Let me define

```
\let\save@pgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\save@endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture
\let\endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture

\preto\spypgf@picture{\let\pgf@picture\save@pgf@picture}
\patchcmd\spypgf@picture{\pgfsys@beginscope}{%
   \pgfkeys{
      /tikz/spy scope/.append code={
         \let\tikz@atbegin@scope\relax%
         \let\tikz@atend@scope\relax%
      }
   }%
   \let\tikz@lib@spy@save=\tikz@lib@spy@collection%
   \setbox\tikz@lib@spybox=\hbox\bgroup\bgroup%
      \let\spy=\tikz@lib@spy@parse%
      \pgfsys@beginscope%
}{%
   % We successfully injected the starting code.
   \patchcmd\endspypgfpicture{\pgfsys@endscope}{%
         \pgfsys@endscope%
      \egroup\egroup%
      \let\endpgfpicture\save@endspypgfpicture%
      {%
         % First print the original picture
         \copy\tikz@lib@spybox%
         % Then reset everything for the spybox
         \pgfsetcolor{.}%
         \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
         \pgftransformreset%
         \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\pgfutil@empty%
         \let\pgf@setlengthorig=\setlength%
         \let\pgf@addtolengthorig=\addtolength%
         \let\pgf@selectfontorig=\selectfont%
         \let\setlength=\pgf@setlength%
         \let\addtolength=\pgf@addtolength%
         \let\selectfont=\pgf@selectfont%
         \nullfont\spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt%
         \tracinglostchars=%
          \ifnum\tracinglostchars>2 2\else\tracinglostchars\fi
         \hbox to0pt{%
            \tikz@installcommands%
            \expandafter\scope\layeredspypicture@params%
               \iftikz@handle@active@code%
                  \tikz@switchoff@shorthands%
               \fi%
               \tikz@lib@spy@collection%
            \endscope%
         }%
      }%
      \global\let\tikz@lib@spy@collection=\tikz@lib@spy@save%
   }{}{%
      \let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture % Keep a consistent state
      \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (2).}%
   }
}{%
   \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (1).}%
}%

\newenvironment{layeredspypicture}[2][standard]{%
   \begingroup%
      \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/set layers=#1}
      \edef\layeredspypicture@params{[{every picture,#2}]}
      \let\pgf@picture\spypgf@picture%
      \let\endpgfpicture\endspypgfpicture%
      \tikzpicture[{#2}]%
}{%
      \endtikzpicture%
   \endgroup%
}
```

The basic usage is to replace `tikzpicture` by `layeredspypicture`. The parameters to the `tikzpicture`, including the spy options, are now mandatory; the layer list name is optional (use e.g. `axis on top` if desired). This automatically enables layers on a top level so that we can see anything at all. Then, it redefines the environments in such a way that the usual `spy` behavior is turned off but you can still use the keys as normal. Then, the capturing box is installed at a very early level. When the picture is ended, we print the box. Then, we reinstall all the styles as they were at the beginning of the picture (probably not all the commands are needed, but I had no patience to find out which) and then open a new scope which the original parameters you gave to `layeredspypicture`. In here, we draw what was ordered by the use of `\spy`, which now contains all layers. Note that this implies that the zoom will always be on the very foreground.

Only use this environment with the `spy` style attached to it. In the current version, you cannot introduce a nested scope with another `spy` style because the original code is disabled. This could of course be improved (spying on a spy is not possible at the moment - and even if it is, only the outermost spy will contain all layers. Fixing this is general would require quite a bit of effort). Also, I currently get an overfull `\hbox` hint which could also be switched of at some place.

**Update 2023-08-24:**

- `standalone` now seems to redefine `\endtikzpicture` at a later stage, so we cannot capture its definition before the document begins. The new approach only captures it right before the picture starts.
- The defaults layer lists of `pgfplots` seem to be a bit messed up. `default` is still documented, but it contains `pre main` (which is also still documented). But `pre main` does not exist. And if we declare it, it doesn't seem to be invoked. So now, we use `standard` instead of `default`.
- The parser of `pgfkeys` appears to have changed a bit, which requires shifting some braces.

Comment: very nice explanation! (The amount of special code is a bit overwhelming but the hint to wirte `\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/set layers, spy...]...` was perfect for me =) ) Thx

Comment: I tried your last solution (which is supposed to make everything work properly if I got you right). And using it as `\begin{layeredspypicture}{spy using outlines...` I get the following error at the end of my figure's `\end{axis}`: `Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'pre main' could not be found. Maybe you misspelled it?. \end{axis}`. Any idea?

Comment: @mranvick, I checked why this error happened and updated the code (might be worth opening an issue with pgfplots). Which led to some new errors which I think were due to updates in standalone. The new code should fix all the problems at the current state of packages.

Comment: @BenjaminDesef, I tested your latest fix, which works, and I published an answer accordingly to make it simpler for people to use it without having to dive into technical explanations. Thank you very much!!! Also, I tested your two other fixes with the M(N)WE of my answer: the first one makes the axes and fill between to appear but there is still no fill in the magnifying glass. The second one makes both axes AND fill disappear in BOTH figures (the one without spy and the one with it), so it does not work... Please note that I put some axes in my M(N)WE compared to the original answer.

Comment: @BenjaminDesef, there was a ticket in the PGFPlot bug tracking system: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/103/, migrated here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/103. I thus created a ticket in the PGF bug tracking system here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1277. Please do not hesitate to contribute at this latter address. I must admit that I am by no mean enough of a TeX expert to be of any help on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

According to Stefan Pinnow's comment this is due to a bug in either `fillbetween` or `spy` libraries. I managed to find a workaround for this specific case. I manually drawn the top line with `\closedcycle` and `fill = gray`, then the lower line again with `\closedcycle` and `fill = white`. I had to manually add a vertical offset so that both lines were drawn above zero, and draw them twice --- once with filling and no drawing and once with drawing and no filling --- to avoid having dashed lines go to zero. There is still a very faint line along zero, but it is almost unnoticeable.

It might not be suitable for all use cases and it is certainly more manual work, but the result is acceptable for me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ticks = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    axis line style = {draw=none},
]
\addplot [
    name path=lower,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    name path=upper,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    fill = gray,
    opacity=.1
] fill between[of=upper and lower];
\addplot[
    no marks,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    axis line style = {draw=none},
]
\addplot [
    name path=lower,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    name path=upper,
    no marks,
    dashed,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot [
    fill = gray,
    opacity=.1
] fill between[of=upper and lower];
\addplot[
    no marks,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.5, 1);
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 5, 0);
\end{axis}
\spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    axis line style = {draw=none},
]
\addplot[
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 100,
    fill = gray,
    fill opacity = .1,
    draw = none,
] expression {3 + sin(deg(x))} \closedcycle;
\addplot[
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 100,
    fill = white,
    draw = none,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))} \closedcycle;
\addplot[
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 100,
    dashed,
] expression {3 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 100,
    dashed,
] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[
    no marks,
    domain = 0:10,
    samples = 40,
] expression {2 + sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.5, 1);
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 5, 2);
\end{axis}
\spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem in TeXLive (`texlive/texlive-full` Docker image) when magnifying a part of my line chart removed the grid lines. My workaround is far more primitive though: nesting `tikzpicture`.

### Working sample

I managed to get your example working by removing both spy coordinates from the plot and nesting the plot in a node. The spy is then placed outside of this nested image - unfortunately positioned manually, for which I used the `positioning` TikZ package.

Keep in mind that positioning things manually is tedious and you will likely **not** hit the exact spot that you'd have when using PGFPlot's positioning, however this workaround worked for *me*.

```latex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
    ]
    \node at (0,0) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                ticks = none,
                axis x line* = top,
                axis line style = {draw=none},
            ]
            \addplot [
                name path=lower,
                no marks,
                dashed,
                domain = 0:10,
                samples = 40,
            ] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [
                name path=upper,
                no marks,
                dashed,
                domain = 0:10,
                samples = 40,
            ] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [
                fill = gray,
                opacity=.1
            ] fill between[of=upper and lower];
            \addplot[
                no marks,
                domain = 0:10,
                samples = 40,
            ] expression {sin(deg(x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \coordinate (spy point) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[above=2.75cm of spy point] (magnifying glass);

    \spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Diff

Since it's hard to spot the changes in the sample, here's the diff:

```
diff --git a/original.tex b/modified.tex
index 9b9c997..a3e2073 100644
--- a/original.tex
+++ b/modified.tex
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 \documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{spy}
+\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \begin{document}
@@ -38,6 +39,8 @@
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
         spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
     ]
+    \node at (0,0) {
+        \begin{tikzpicture}
             \begin{axis}[
                 ticks = none,
                 axis x line* = top,
@@ -66,9 +69,13 @@
                 domain = 0:10,
                 samples = 40,
             ] expression {sin(deg(x))};
-\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.5, 1);
-\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 5, 0);
             \end{axis}
+        \end{tikzpicture}
+    };
+    
+    \coordinate (spy point) at (0,0);
+    \coordinate[above=2.75cm of spy point] (magnifying glass);
+    
     \spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** a simple copy-paste workaround is given at the end of this answer.

I thought it might be worth summing-up [Benjamin Desef's detailed answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463293/222633) in a single — hopefully more understandable — answer, so that non experts can better make use of his in-depth understanding of the topic. The reader is free to read the above-mentioned answer for a more detailed analysis of the problem, and all credits go to Benjamin Desef.

### Short minimum NOT working exemple

Shortening the original M(N)WE leads to:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot [name path=lower] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [name path=upper, dashed] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [fill = gray, opacity=.1] fill between[of=upper and lower];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
        ]
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot [name path=lower] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [name path=upper, dashed] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [fill = gray, opacity=.1] fill between[of=upper and lower];
            \coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.35, 0.7);
            \coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, -1);
        \end{axis}
        \spy on (spy point) in node [fill=white] at (magnifying glass);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces two figures, the second clearly indicating that `spy` and `fill between` do not work well together:

[image]
[image]

While the first one works well without spy (fill between only), the second one is all wrong, with axes and the filled area disappearing.

### Short minimum working exemple

Including some corrections lead to the following code:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\let\save@pgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\save@endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture
\let\endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture

\preto\spypgf@picture{\let\pgf@picture\save@pgf@picture}
\patchcmd\spypgf@picture{\pgfsys@beginscope}{%
    \pgfkeys{
        /tikz/spy scope/.append code={
            \let\tikz@atbegin@scope\relax%
            \let\tikz@atend@scope\relax%
        }
    }%
    \let\tikz@lib@spy@save=\tikz@lib@spy@collection%
    \setbox\tikz@lib@spybox=\hbox\bgroup\bgroup%
    \let\spy=\tikz@lib@spy@parse%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
}{%
    % We successfully injected the starting code.
    \patchcmd\endspypgfpicture{\pgfsys@endscope}{%
        \pgfsys@endscope%
        \egroup\egroup%
        \let\endpgfpicture\save@endspypgfpicture%
        {%
            % First print the original picture
            \copy\tikz@lib@spybox%
            % Then reset everything for the spybox
            \pgfsetcolor{.}%
            \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
            \pgftransformreset%
            \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\pgfutil@empty%
            \let\pgf@setlengthorig=\setlength%
            \let\pgf@addtolengthorig=\addtolength%
            \let\pgf@selectfontorig=\selectfont%
            \let\setlength=\pgf@setlength%
            \let\addtolength=\pgf@addtolength%
            \let\selectfont=\pgf@selectfont%
            \nullfont\spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt%
            \tracinglostchars=%
            \ifnum\tracinglostchars>2 2\else\tracinglostchars\fi
            \hbox to0pt{%
                \tikz@installcommands%
                \expandafter\scope\layeredspypicture@params%
                \iftikz@handle@active@code%
                \tikz@switchoff@shorthands%
                \fi%
                \tikz@lib@spy@collection%
                \endscope%
            }%
        }%
        \global\let\tikz@lib@spy@collection=\tikz@lib@spy@save%
    }{}{%
        \let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture % Keep a consistent state
        \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (2).}%
    }
}{%
    \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (1).}%
}%

\newenvironment{layeredspypicture}[2][standard]{%
    \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/set layers=#1}
    \edef\layeredspypicture@params{[{every picture,#2}]}
    \let\pgf@picture\spypgf@picture%
    \let\endpgfpicture\endspypgfpicture%
    \tikzpicture[{#2}]%
}{%
    \endtikzpicture%
    \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot [name path=lower] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [name path=upper, dashed] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [fill = gray, opacity=.1] fill between[of=upper and lower];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{layeredspypicture}{
        spy using outlines = {circle,size=2cm,magnification=3,connect spies},
        }
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot [name path=lower] expression {-1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [name path=upper, dashed] expression {1 + sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot [fill = gray, opacity=.1] fill between[of=upper and lower];
            \coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: 0.35, 0.7);
            \coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, -1);
        \end{axis}
        \spy on (spy point) in node [fill=white] at (magnifying glass);
    \end{layeredspypicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following figures:

[image]
[image]

Which behave exactly as expected.

### How to make it work?

In order to use this workaround in all situations, you will need to add to your LaTeX file the following packages:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
```

Preamble code:

```
\let\save@pgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture
\let\save@endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture
\let\endspypgfpicture\endpgfpicture

\preto\spypgf@picture{\let\pgf@picture\save@pgf@picture}
\patchcmd\spypgf@picture{\pgfsys@beginscope}{%
    \pgfkeys{
        /tikz/spy scope/.append code={
            \let\tikz@atbegin@scope\relax%
            \let\tikz@atend@scope\relax%
        }
    }%
    \let\tikz@lib@spy@save=\tikz@lib@spy@collection%
    \setbox\tikz@lib@spybox=\hbox\bgroup\bgroup%
    \let\spy=\tikz@lib@spy@parse%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
}{%
    % We successfully injected the starting code.
    \patchcmd\endspypgfpicture{\pgfsys@endscope}{%
        \pgfsys@endscope%
        \egroup\egroup%
        \let\endpgfpicture\save@endspypgfpicture%
        {%
            % First print the original picture
            \copy\tikz@lib@spybox%
            % Then reset everything for the spybox
            \pgfsetcolor{.}%
            \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
            \pgftransformreset%
            \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\pgfutil@empty%
            \let\pgf@setlengthorig=\setlength%
            \let\pgf@addtolengthorig=\addtolength%
            \let\pgf@selectfontorig=\selectfont%
            \let\setlength=\pgf@setlength%
            \let\addtolength=\pgf@addtolength%
            \let\selectfont=\pgf@selectfont%
            \nullfont\spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt%
            \tracinglostchars=%
            \ifnum\tracinglostchars>2 2\else\tracinglostchars\fi
            \hbox to0pt{%
                \tikz@installcommands%
                \expandafter\scope\layeredspypicture@params%
                \iftikz@handle@active@code%
                \tikz@switchoff@shorthands%
                \fi%
                \tikz@lib@spy@collection%
                \endscope%
            }%
        }%
        \global\let\tikz@lib@spy@collection=\tikz@lib@spy@save%
    }{}{%
        \let\spypgf@picture\pgf@picture % Keep a consistent state
        \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (2).}%
    }
}{%
    \ClassWarning{bd.cls}{Unable to patch pgfpicture for layered graphics spying (1).}%
}%

\newenvironment{layeredspypicture}[2][standard]{%
    \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/set layers=#1}
    \edef\layeredspypicture@params{[{every picture,#2}]}
    \let\pgf@picture\spypgf@picture%
    \let\endpgfpicture\endspypgfpicture%
    \tikzpicture[{#2}]%
}{%
    \endtikzpicture%
    \endgroup%
}
```

And finally, you will need to replace your:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[option1=foo, option2=bar, etc.]
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By:

```
\begin{layeredspypicture}{option1=foo, option2=bar, etc.}
    ...
\end{layeredspypicture}
```

That is to say, replace `tikzpicture` by `layeredspypicture`, and replace the `[]` following it which denotes its optional arguments by `{}` denoting mandatory arguments.